# How to add a External source link to a versionone asset (TASK) through Python SDK

Tags: python, versionone

We are creating a customization where we would like to link every code related TASK to a bug.

My Plan is to check a task for category "Code" and check if it has a bug in bugtracking system. If not we will create a bug in bug tracking system and attach it to the TASK as below

> ```
>  Reference = BugId 
>  Source = Bugzilla 
>  link = task.Links.first()
>      link.url = "Bug tracking url"
> ```

So here lies the problem, through Python SDK, what is the function to be called to create a Link which should get attached to the TASK and have the url of the bug tracking system in the URL attribute.

When I next query for Links in the corresponding task asset I should be able to fetch the bug tracking URL through

> task.Links[0].URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to achieve it is to create a link and attach the asset to the asset property of the link

For Ex:
v1 is an instacnce of V1Meta package from v1pysdk

```
asset = v1.asset_from_oid('Task:2209')
taskSource = v1.TaskSource.where(Name="Bugzilla").first()
```

Now create a link like below

```
new_link = v1.Link.create(
            Name="Bugzilla",
            URL="{0}".format(newbug.weburl),
            OnMenu="true",
            Asset=asset
)
asset.Source=taskSource
v1.commit()
```

Above code will create a link and the link is attached to the asset